# Whats the error in my php function?

Tags: php

I have a function a. That is re used in many times without any problem. But now  i cant call the function.**This is my function**

```
function a($a,&$b){
        // functions code here
        }
```

I calling function a like this.

```
a(3,null);
```

Whats the error with my code?

Comment: How can we tell you what's wrong with your function when you haven't shown us the code inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll see that you get an error message along the lines of

```
PHP Fatal error:  Only variables can be passed by reference in SOMETHING.php on line xxx
```

This is because your function is saying that its second parameter is a reference (i.e. `&$b`) and this requires that you pass a variable.  You are actually passing `null` which is not a variable, hence the problem.

If you require the second parameter as a reference (and one way of fixing this might be to remove that requirement) pass along a variable that is set to null.  E.g.

```
$c = null;
a(3, $c);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to pass `null` by reference.

```
function a($a,&$b){
        // functions code here
        }

a(3,$otherVar);
// A copy of 3 is sent to the function.
// $otherVar is actually passed to the function
```

You could at a pinch also use something like this:

```
$null = 0; // Throwaway variable
a($a, $null);
```

But if you are passing by reference, *why* do you want to send it a null? Surely the bit of the code that modifies the contents of the second variable does this for a purpose?

What you are doing is almost a perfect example of wanting to use function overloading by the way, it is a shame that PHP doesn't support this.

Another idea you might want to consider - Pass it an array as the parameter like this:

```
$myVars=array( 'first' => $a, 'second' => $otherVar);
a($myVars);
```

You can pass as many items as you want, you can keep it as a pass by reference, but you end up changing the array, not the variables directly. In your function, you can simply choose to never modify the `first` and do as needed with the `second` (if it exists).

Optional Parameters can be used, but are not as intuitive as you might think and wouldn't work on the example you gave:

```
function makecoffee($var, &$type = "cappuccino")
{
    return "Making a cup of $type.\n";
}
echo makecoffee(1);
echo makecoffee(1,null);
```

Output:

```
Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in 
/var/www/test.php on line 7
```

This is because the `null` still cannot be passed by reference. You could however use the first echo without errors.

Comment: @EbinPaulose Also gave you another suggestion you might want to consider.

Comment: alertnatively php supports optional arguments which is a way of making it look like function overloading see my answer below

Comment: @ianace Optional Parameters still cannot be passed by reference unless they are a variable, so the user could not pass a `null`. I did however make an edit and added some discussion on these.

Answer (score -1):

It should be :

```
 function a($a,$b=false){
        // functions code here
    }
```